# How to detect which submit button is clicked in jquery

Tags: jquery, submit

If I have 2 submit buttons on my form, **is it possible to detect which one was clicked** in jquery?

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Button 1">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Button 2">
```

This is consistently returning "Button 1"

```
alert($("input[name=submit]").val());
```

Comment: You have 2 inputs with the same ID and same name (non-array). That's bad.

Comment: @EvanMulawski They're not IDs and it's not bad. It's completely valid, like having radio buttons with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need unique ids...using your supplied HTML:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function() {
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Edit: I agree you should change the name on one of the buttons though

Comment: No problem, do you understand why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have unique IDs:

```
<input id="submit1" name="submit" type="submit" value="Button 1">
<input id="submit1" name="submit" type="submit" value="Button 2">
```

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to have unique ids for each button and you could do this:

```
$('input').on('click', function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

else if you want to keep your current structure and return the value you need this:

```
$('input').on('click', function(){
    // the value inside attr() can be any property of the element
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
});
```